# Use Python to extract content with the same field in JSON regardless of the hierarchy

Tags: python, json, parsing

here is a demo of my current json file:

```
school=
[
{'grade':6,
'students':
[
{'id': 300515,
 'name': 'George',
 'height': 1.75},
{'id': 300516,
 'name': 'Lucy',
 'height': 1.65}]},
{'grade':5,
'students':
[
{'id': 300517,
 'name': 'Edward',
 'height': 1.80},
{'id': 300518,
 'name': 'Olivia',
 'height': 1.70}]}
]
```

What I want to achieve is to concatenate **all** the student names into one string, regardless of which grade they belong to (i.e. "George Lucy Edward Olivia").

However, the hierarchy of the real data is much more complex than this demo, which means there are even more layers on top of `school` level here (perhaps you can imagine like district, city, state etc. in this demo). Currently I can only use multiple `for` loops to achieve this.

But I want to know whether there are any shortcuts to achieve this. For example, use one function to extract all the contents in json **as long as they belong to same field and regardless of the hierarchy.** Thanks.

Comment: yes, you can do that using recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion using this way.

```
school=[
    {'grade':6,'students':[{'id': 300515, 'name': 'George', 'height': 1.75},
    {'id': 300516, 'name': 'Lucy', 'height': 1.65}]},
    {'grade':5,'students':[{'id': 300517, 'name': 'Edward', 'height': 1.80},
    {'id': 300518, 'name': 'Olivia','height': 1.70}]}
]


def getNames(json,names):
  if isinstance(json,dict):
    for key,value in json.items():
      if 'name' is key:
        names.append(value)
      if isinstance(value,list):
        for line in value:
          if isinstance(line,dict):
            getNames(line,names)
  elif isinstance(json,list):
    for line in json:
      if isinstance(line,dict):
        getNames(line,names)


names = []
getNames(school,names)
print(names)
```

if name is present as key in above json then its values will get added in list of names else list remains empty.